How to create a specific filter, in the filter model, not present in the table?

For example: I have an external checkbox that changes the query
parameters for the backend. When the user activates this checkbox, I
want to change the filter model and then the table will create a new
query with the new filter. Is this possible?
Now I just create a hidden column for manipulate the filter model. Because
tables can't work with fields in the filter model which are not presented in
columnDefs.


Support custom fields in the filter model which not presented in columnDefs
